# How to send http request from android app to backend server in the computer

Tags: android, http, request

I developed an android app as front-end and spring boot backend server.
Now, I want to send requests from an android app to the backend server.

But, I'm using the phone to run an android app instead of the emulator.
The IP address on my phone 192.168.8.100 and IP address on my computer  192.168.8.101. Those, are different.

So, how can I do that?

I used the retrofit library to send the http requests to the backend server.
In my `AppContants` class, I defined the base URL as follows.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.8.101:8080/apeevent/api/v1/";
```

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

In `AppConstants` class use

```
public static final String BASE_URL ="http://192.168.8.100:8080/";
//public static final String BASE_URL ="http://192.168.8.101:8080/";
```

Define separately for each URLs:

```
public static final String apeevent ="apeevent/api/v1/";
```

When you want to run it from particular URL comment the other one.